# Objects and java GUI

Tags: java, swing, object, user-interface

Consider the following code.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;


    public class RobotControl extends JFrame {
        public static void main (String args[])  {

RobotControl GUI = new RobotControl();
GUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
GUI.setSize(500,500);
GUI.setVisible(true);
GUI.setTitle("RobotControl");
}


   private Finch myf;
   private JButton front;
   private JButton back;
   private JButton left;


   public RobotControl() { 
   myf = new Finch();
   setLayout (new FlowLayout());


   front = new JButton("front");
   add(front);
   front.addActionListener(new FrontButtonListener(myf));
   back = new JButton("back");
   add(back);
   back.addActionListener(new BackButtonListener(myf));
   left = new JButton("left");
   add(left);
   left.addActionListener(new LeftButtonListener(myf));
   }


    public class FowardButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    public FowardButtonListener(Finch myf) {
    }
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        myf.setWheelVelocities(100,100,10000);
        }
       }
        public class BackwardButtonListener implements ActionListener{
        public BackwardButtonListener(Finch myf){   
        }  
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
              myf.setWheelVelocities(-100,-100,10000);
                      }
             }  
                   public class LeftButtonListener implements ActionListener{
                    public LeftButtonListener(Finch myf){
                     }
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
                        myf.setWheelVelocities(0, 200, 1000);
                        }        
                  }
```

Now, the program creates a GUI that operates a small Robot. Three options to move either foward, backward or turn left. I want the robot to wait for all three buttons or any combination of buttons to be clicked before it starts moving, as at the moment, the robot moves immediately i click any button.Any help is appreciated. I only started learning java recently, so my knowledge is very limited.

Comment: 1) three boolean variables in the GUI could work. 2) I'm sure you could work this out with a little effort. 3) When posting code here, please make sure it is formatted well, in particular the indentation. Yours is a bit difficult to read near the bottom, and I'm sure you're not trying to make it more difficult for us to help you, so why not fix this?

Comment: I think you need to specify a bit further the behaviour of your program. What will happen after the program has run? Do you need the buttons to be reset, and then wait again for all the 3 of them to be pressed?

Comment: The program creates a GUI that operates a small Robot. Three options to move either foward, backward or turn left. I want the robot to wait for all three buttons or any combination of buttons to be clicked before it starts moving, as at the moment, the robot moves immediately i click any button.

Comment: that's not the task of the ui, instead change the implementation of Finch to move only if ready (f.i. after all three values are updated)

Comment: how would you suggest i do that. Am fairly new to java, so please forgive my Naivity.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question properly then:

Declare a `boolean` variable for each button, and when each button is clicked make flag defined for the button to true. And in event of button check whether all flags are true or not. IF true then don't wait, if false then wait.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a boolean value for each. When a button is clicked, change the boolean value to true.